# (this) usage in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I have the HTML element like this below

```
<div class="myclassname" data-barcolor="#000000"></div>
```

And I am trying to get these "data-barcolor" property using (this). keyword, instead of using classname..like below

```
$('.myclassname').easyPieChart({
    barColor : $(this).attr('data-barcolor'),
});
```

It doesn't work properly.
But

```
$('.myclassname').easyPieChart({
    barColor : $('.myclassname.').attr('data-barcolor'),
});
```

Works perfectly.

By Using classname i can't get the values dynamically. I have more than one class in the same name with different values. so how to get the values in jquery!

Comment: It's because `$(this)` in that context doesn't occur within the `$('.myclassname')` context, it's within it's outer (calling) context that it's being called from. It doesn't gain scope that way from that selector, in other words because that expression is immediately evaluated.

Comment: Look up scope in jQuery/Javascript. In your case, you are still in global scope when you're using `$(this)`, which will most likely be `undefined`. You can use `$(this)` if you're inside a anonymous function, such as `.each` or a event handler such as `.on('event', function() { /* I'm a handler */ })` and `$(this)` would work as expected.

Comment: @ninty9notout - `this` in the global scope points to `window`, not `undefined`. There is also no indication this is in the global scope; that's a guess.

Comment: I just tried it, doing `$(this)` surrounded in `$(function() {});` returns the `document` as a jQuery object - as doing this is a shorthand of doing `$(document).ready([...]).

Answer (score 6):

You can use `each` loop for this:

```
$('.myclassname').each(function() {
    $(this).easyPieChart({
        barColor : $(this).data('barcolor'),
    });
});
```

Documentation also states that `barColor` can be a function, however unfortunately this function is invoked in wrong context (as I can assume from reading [sources](https://github.com/rendro/easy-pie-chart/blob/master/src/renderer/canvas.js)) so you can't go with natural `barColor: function() { return $(this).attr(...); }` way.